# Release app has bugs that weren't there when testing

Tags: android, camera, release

My app is different after downloading from Play Store.  If I go back to the same app and put it on my phone from Android Studio, it works fine.  Specifically the camera does not work and the images don't automatically rotate to the correct orientation.  It's a strange issue, so please ask for clarification, if needed.

Comment: do you have more info? you use diferente flavors in the app? what is the error logs you receive?

Comment: How are you installing it from Android Studio?

Comment: Even though it's been more than 24 hours, looks like Google Play Store still says it's version 1.1, which was before the update.  It does have the text telling what is new in the update.  Do you think it's still the old version?  Maybe this is a problem with Google Play Store.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If your use progaurd for your release version, you should check if you have a special string or a class name that progaurd changes it to a new obfuscated string, so the logic will raise a nullpointerexception, etc. please add the class where it crashes